# chromatic polynomial of unicyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory

i need your help as i have the below exercise:

**Two graphs are chromatically equivalent if they have the same chromatic
polynomial. A unicyclic graph is a connected graph containing exactly one cycle. Which unicyclic graphs of the same order are chromatically equivalent?**

1st step: what i need to do is to compute the chromatic polynomial of unicyclic graph with order $n$ ( $n$-vertices) and cycle length $k$.
2nd step: consider two unicyclic graphs G and G' with n order and length $k$ and $k'$ respectively, and deduce something on the values $k, k'$.

i cannot find anything on internet which can help me.

what i think is that:
the chromatic polynomial of unicyclic graph it should be $P_k(x)=x(x-1)^n-1$.
right?

but then i do not know what else to do.
Please help. thanks